# How can I find the difference between two times that have milliseconds

Tags: time, vb6, formula, precision, milliseconds

USING VB6 ONLY...

I have two times and need to get the time between them.  I have a file that contains times in the format `"08:34:45:734"` and I just need to calculate the time difference between the two values.

Example:

```
08:34:12:744
08:34:45:734
```

I need the output to generate the correct time, including milliseconds, between the two times. I tried to convert to double and subtract, but I can't seem to get all the way back to `H:M:S:m` time format that I need.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. VB dates do not include the number of ms but you could just strip the ms off and calculate the difference yourself.

```
Private Function GetTimeDiff(strDate1 As String, strDate2 As String) As String

    Dim fNeg As Boolean
    Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date
    Dim ms1 As Long, ms2 As Long

    ' Assign earliest date to dt1...
    If strDate1 <= strDate2 Then
        dt1 = Left$(strDate1, 8)
        dt2 = Left$(strDate2, 8)
        ms1 = Right$(strDate1, 3)
        ms2 = Right$(strDate2, 3)
    Else
        dt1 = Left$(strDate2, 8)
        dt2 = Left$(strDate1, 8)
        ms1 = Right$(strDate2, 3)
        ms2 = Right$(strDate1, 3)
        fNeg = True
    End If

    ' If ms of starting time > ms of ending time, add a second before subtraction...
    Dim ms As Long
    If ms1 > ms2 Then
        dt1 = DateAdd("s", 1, dt1)
        ms = (1000 - ms1) + ms2
    Else
        ms = ms2 - ms1
    End If

    ' Subtract dates, get difference in seconds...
    Dim h As Long, m As Long, s As Long
    s = DateDiff("s", dt1, dt2)

    ' Convert seconds to H:M:S...
    h = s \ 3600
    s = s Mod 3600
    m = s \ 60
    s = s Mod 60

    GetTimeDiff = IIf(fNeg, "-", "") & h & ":" & m & ":" & s & ":" & ms

End Function
```

Call it by passing your string values and it will return an `h:m:s:ms` string:

```
Debug.Print GetTimeDiff("08:34:12:744", "08:34:45:734") ' => "0:0:32:990"
```

If the first date is later than the second, you'll get a negative value:

```
Debug.Print GetTimeDiff("10:34:12:744", "08:34:45:734") ' => "-1:59:27:10"
```

Answer (score 1):

My take on this attempts to allow for sign indicators and results that wrap into days (more than 23:59:59:999 or less than -23:59:59:999).  If these aren't an issue for you then you can ignore both sign indictors and days since both "+" and zero days are suppressed in the result.

```
Private Function ToLong(ByVal HMSms As String) As Long
    'Valid value range is -2:20:31:23:647 to +2:20:31:23:647,
    'Sign indicator optional, days position optional.
    Dim Parts() As String
    Dim SChar As String
    Dim Sign As Long

    SChar = Left$(HMSms, 1)
    If SChar = "+" Or SChar = "-" Then
        HMSms = Mid$(HMSms, 2)
        Sign = IIf(SChar = "+", 1, -1)
    Else
        Sign = 1
    End If
    Parts = Split(HMSms, ":")
    If UBound(Parts) < 4 Then
        Parts = Split("0:" & HMSms, ":")
    End If
    ToLong = CLng(Parts(4)) _
           + CLng(Parts(3)) * 1000& _
           + CLng(Parts(2)) * 1000& * 60& _
           + CLng(Parts(1)) * 1000& * 60& * 60& _
           + CLng(Parts(0)) * 1000& * 60& * 60& * 24&
    ToLong = ToLong * Sign
End Function

Private Function Diff(ByVal Minu As String, ByVal Subtra As String) As String
    'Result suppresses positive sign indicator and 0 value in days position.
    Dim DiffLong As Long
    Dim SChar As String

    DiffLong = ToLong(Minu) - ToLong(Subtra)
    If DiffLong < 0 Then
        SChar = "-"
        DiffLong = -DiffLong
    End If
    Diff = "0:00:00:00:000"
    Mid$(Diff, 1, 1) = Format$(DiffLong \ (1000& * 60& * 60& * 24&), "0")
    Mid$(Diff, 3, 2) = Format$(DiffLong \ (1000& * 60& * 60&) Mod 24&, "00")
    Mid$(Diff, 6, 2) = Format$(DiffLong \ (1000& * 60&) Mod 60&, "00")
    Mid$(Diff, 9, 2) = Format$(DiffLong \ 1000& Mod 60&, "00")
    Mid$(Diff, 12, 3) = Format$(DiffLong Mod 1000&, "000")
    If Left$(Diff, 1) = "0" Then Diff = Mid$(Diff, 3)
    Diff = SChar & Diff
End Function
```

Some test case results:

```
08:34:45:734 - 08:34:12:744 = 00:00:32:990
08:34:45:734 - 08:34:40:734 = 00:00:05:000
08:34:12:744 - 08:34:45:734 = -00:00:32:990
-00:00:00:000 - +00:00:00:000 = 00:00:00:000
+00:00:00:000 - 00:00:00:001 = -00:00:00:001
1:00:00:00:000 - 00:00:00:001 = 23:59:59:999
-2:00:00:00:000 - 00:00:00:000 = -2:00:00:00:000
-12:00:00:000 - 12:00:00:000 = -1:00:00:00:000
-23:59:59:999 - 00:00:00:000 = -23:59:59:999
```